# Unable to call Private Address using Public Address (AWS EC2)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have 2 Ec2 instances (Public and Private)

In Public:  I hosted angular site over xampp

In Private: I hosted Node server (port 3000)

In angular I used (http://10.0.1.68:3000) for API calling
When I open Chrome Browser in Public Ec2 then angular site is working fine. like localhost/home. Then he calls Private server (http://10.0.1.68:3000) and get the data from Database.

But when I use Public Address (37.22.XXX.XX) then Angular design loads in my browser but it not calling the Node API with http://10.0.1.68:3000
Any Idea ????

Comment: Is the "Node API with http://10.0.1.68:3000" call being made on the client side, i.e., from the browser?

Comment: Yes, this link is embedded inside the Angular Site.

Answer (score 0):

Since the call to Node API (10.0.1.68:3000) is done on the **client side** (based on the comments), it will fail.

The reason is that the Node server is hosted in a private subnet of the VPC. Since its private, it **can't be accessed from the internet**.

It works from the EC2 instance, since the ec2 instance is in the same VPC.

The simplest solution would be to place the Node API in the public subnet as well, as internet access is required to call it. Alternative way would involve setting up a proxy server in a public subnet to proxy api calls from the internet into the private subnet. [API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) could also be setup. This way your front-end would call API getaway endpoints which would in turn call your private Node API.

Comment: @DeepDahelay Hi. You don't have to, but its simplest way. If you call your api from the internet, it must have public IP. Address of `10.0.1.68:3000` is not routable over the internet. You can also setup API gateway to access your Node api through the gateway.